# Faster way to build a matrix of expected frequencies from a sparse matrix of counts

Tags: python, performance, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a Compressed Sparse Row matrix containing counts. I want to build a matrix containing the expected frequencies for these counts. Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

#m is a csr_matrix

col_total = m.sum(axis=0)
row_total = m.sum(axis=1)
n = int(col_total.sum(axis=1))
A = coo_matrix(m)

for i,j in zip(A.row,A.col):
    m[i,j]= col_total.item(j)*row_total.item(i)/n
```

This works fine on a small matrix. On a bigger matrix (>1Gb), the for loop takes several days to run. Is there any way I could make this faster?

Comment: Is `row_total.item(i)` supposed to be in the denominator?

Comment: I'm not seeing how this computation is supposed to produce expected frequencies.

Comment: You're right, it should be col_total.item(j)*row_total.item(i)/n
I'll edit now.

Comment: @kormak, what do you mean by `>1Gb`?

Comment: I'm still not seeing what this result is supposed to represent. If you feed it `[[1, 0], [0, 1]]`, you get `[[0.5, 0], [[0, 0.5]]`. But if you feed it `[[1, eps], [eps, 1]]`, where `eps` is some tiny but nonzero number, you get roughly `[[0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5]]`. And should we be concerned that feeding it `[[1, 1], [1, 0]]` results in expected frequencies greater than 1?

Comment: @innoSPG I mean the file containing the matrix is over one gigabyte.

Comment: @user2357112 The code does what I want it to do. The only thing I'm concerned about here is performance.

Comment: @kormak: If it does what you want it to do, then what you want it to do is *really, really* weird. We can suggest ways to make it go faster, but for best results, we need to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a little on **@hpaulj**'s answer, you can get rid of the `for` loop by creating the output matrix directly from the expected frequencies and the row/column indices of the non-zero elements in `m`:

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np

def fast_efreqs(m):

    col_total = np.array(m.sum(axis=0)).ravel()
    row_total = np.array(m.sum(axis=1)).ravel()

    # I'm casting this to an int for consistency with your version, but it's
    # not clear to me why you would want to do this...
    grand_total = int(col_total.sum())

    ridx, cidx = m.nonzero()            # indices of non-zero elements in m
    efreqs = row_total[ridx] * col_total[cidx] / grand_total

    return sparse.coo_matrix((efreqs, (ridx, cidx)))
```

For comparison, here's your original code as a function:

```
def orig_efreqs(m):

    col_total = m.sum(axis=0)
    row_total = m.sum(axis=1)
    n = int(col_total.sum(axis=1))

    A = sparse.coo_matrix(m)
    for i,j in zip(A.row,A.col):
        m[i,j]= col_total.item(j)*row_total.item(i)/n

    return m
```

Test equivalence on a small matrix:

```
m = sparse.rand(100, 100, density=0.1, format='csr')
print((orig_efreqs(m.copy()) != fast_efreqs(m)).nnz == 0)
# True
```

Benchmark performance on a larger matrix:

```
In [1]: %%timeit m = sparse.rand(10000, 10000, density=0.01, format='csr')
   .....: orig_efreqs(m)
   .....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 2min 25s per loop

In [2]: %%timeit m = sparse.rand(10000, 10000, density=0.01, format='csr')
   .....: fast_efreqs(m)
   .....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 38.3 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

`m.data = (col_total[:,A.col].A*(row_total[A.row,:].T.A)/n)[0]` is a fully vectorized way of calculating `m.data`.  It probably can be cleaned up a bit.  `col_total` is `matrix`, so performing element by element multiplication requires some extra syntax.

I'll demonstrate:

```
In [37]: m=sparse.rand(10,10,.1,'csr')
In [38]: col_total=m.sum(axis=0)
In [39]: row_total=m.sum(axis=1)
In [40]: n=int(col_total.sum(axis=1))

In [42]: A=m.tocoo()

In [46]: for i,j in zip(A.row,A.col):
   ....:         m[i,j]= col_total.item(j)*row_total.item(i)/n
   ....:     

In [49]: m.data
Out[49]: 
array([ 0.39490171,  0.64246488,  0.19310878,  0.13847277,  0.2018023 ,
        0.008504  ,  0.04387622,  0.10903026,  0.37976005,  0.11414632])

In [51]: col_total[:,A.col].A*(row_total[A.row,:].T.A)/n
Out[51]: 
array([[ 0.39490171,  0.64246488,  0.19310878,  0.13847277,  0.2018023 ,
         0.008504  ,  0.04387622,  0.10903026,  0.37976005,  0.11414632]])

In [53]: (col_total[:,A.col].A*(row_total[A.row,:].T.A)/n)[0]
Out[53]: 
array([ 0.39490171,  0.64246488,  0.19310878,  0.13847277,  0.2018023 ,
        0.008504  ,  0.04387622,  0.10903026,  0.37976005,  0.11414632])
```